# Why does explode, preg_split and str_split returns an extra array item

Tags: php, regex

I have been playing arround with this function, basically I want to "separate" a string using \n character but for some reason on this case it generates 3 items:

```
$breaks = explode("\n","\n\n");
```

My goal for this case is just an array with 2 items.

Answer (score 2):

The last occurrence of the delimiter in your string delimits an empty string, e. g.

```
var_dump( explode("\n", "\n") );
```

will return an array with two empty elements, the first slot coming from before the delimiter occurrence, the second value from behind it:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(0) ""
  [1] =>
  string(0) ""
}
```

So you just have to make sure that your string does not end with a delimiter in order to not get an empty element at the end of the array.

Comment: PHP_EOL should only be used if the string was created on the same platform

Comment: Yes right, it means that php running on a windows system will only acknowledge windows specific eol characters. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I'm not sure that altering the input is a sustainable solution for this issue.

Comment: I didn't mean that the content has to be altered, it was just a suggestion to use PHP_EOL as a general consideration. I've deleted this part, because it might be off-topic for this answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by iterate the string with, check [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f77ef39f3cc78e58e14aec08a51b05fa0a4d5a15)

```
$string = "\n\n";
$result = [];
$str = "";
$index = 0;
while($index < strlen($string)){
    if($string[$index] == "\n"){
        $result[] = $str;
        $str = "";
    }else{
        $str .= $string[$index];
    }
    $index++;
}
if($str){
    $result[] = $str;
}
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to match strings of zero or greater length that contain non-vertical-space characters which are followed by a vertical space character.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CqrYD))

```
$text = "\n\n";
var_export(preg_match_all('~\V*(?=\R)~', $text, $matches) ? $matches[0] : []);
```

There will be several patterns and functions to achieve the desired result, but this one seems pretty straight forward to me.

As for explaining your current output, imagine splitting the outward projections on one of your hands based on the gaps between them.  There are four gaps, so your finger count will be 5 (barring any birth defects or mishaps).

Comment: have voted to delete yesterday's offending question. you can help finish it off...

Answer (score 0):

Is the actual problem to select lines of text separated by \n, \r, \r\n or \n\n ?

If different data sources (Win, Linux) are available, different separators must be considered. For this, preg_split is ideal.
An example:

```
$text = " Line1 \n Line2 \r\n Line3 \r Line4 \n\n Line5 \n";

$arr = preg_split('~\R~', $text, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

echo "<pre>".var_export($arr,true)."</pre>";
```

Output

```
array (
  0 => ' Line1 ',
  1 => ' Line2 ',
  2 => ' Line3 ',
  3 => ' Line4 ',
  4 => ' Line5 ',
)
```